# Why are all these email ports listening on a new Windows 8.1 install?

Tags: windows-8.1, email, port

I recently did a fresh install of Windows on a formatted disk, upgrading from Windows 7 Pro to 8.1 Pro. Now I have installed a few things already, including:

- Embarcadero RAD Studio XE8
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015
- Microsoft Office 2013
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
- IObit Advanced System Care & related tools

I remotely did a TCP port scan of this computer, not only scanning for just opened ports, but actually listening ports. Here are the results:

```
OPEN: 25    SMTP
OPEN: 80    HTTP
OPEN: 110   POP3
OPEN: 119   NNTP (Network News Transfer Protocol)
OPEN: 135   DCE or EPMAP
OPEN: 139   NetBIOS Session Service
OPEN: 143   IMAP
OPEN: 443   HTTP over TLS/SSL (HTTPS)
OPEN: 445   Microsoft-DS SMB File Sharing
OPEN: 465   SMTP over TLS/SSL (SMTPS)
OPEN: 563   NNTP over TLS/SSL (NNTPS)
OPEN: 587   Email message submission (SMTP)
OPEN: 993   IMAP over TLS/SSL (IMAPS)
OPEN: 995   POP3 over TLS/SSL (POP3S)
OPEN: 2179  VMConnect to Hyper-V hosts
OPEN: 3389  RDP (Remote Desktop)
OPEN: 5357  Web Service for Devices (WSDAPI)
OPEN: 18864 
OPEN: 49156 
OPEN: 49157
```

I'm concerned in particular about all the email related ports which are listening (SMTP, POP3, etc.), as if my computer is running an email server. I can't imagine any reason why Windows or any of the above software would need to listen on these ports. I'm also always extremely careful what I install, avoiding any kind of malware and only installing things which are approved by the company.

Why is my computer listening on these email related ports? Is this something which is a standard part of Windows and/or the above software? Or am I looking at potential malware already on my machine?

PS - I wrote this port scanner myself (so that I can trust the results) which consists of a TCP Client actually successfully connecting to each of these ports with a 150ms timeout. I ran it from another computer.

Comment: Are you running outlook as part of office?

Comment: @DavidPostill Outlook is a client, not a server. Even with Outlook running this can't happen.

Comment: Are you sure the scanning tool isn't giving bogus results ? This looks as if it reports the contents of a standard services file in stead of doing a real, proper scan. How did you perform the scan ?

Comment: I wrote the scanner myself actually, it actually successfully connects to each and every one of those ports, in this particular case with a 150ms timeout. I ran it from another computer.

Comment: I also manually typed in the descriptions of each, the first 3 don't have descriptions only because I didn't start adding descriptions until the 4th.

Comment: what's the result of [tcpview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/bb897437.aspx)? you can at least find which process is listening on the ports.

Comment: Try a scan using [ShieldsUp](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2)

Comment: Whatever it was, it's not listening now, doing some trial/error with various software.

Comment: In a future IMHO better to use standard OS's tools. Run `netstat -anbo` as administrator and check not only listening port, but you will find what exact program opened it.

Comment: Yeah, at the time of the scan I was busy with other things, tried a few scenarios out but can't get these ports to show up again in any scan.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issue has gone away and is not reproducible so question is not useful for others.